# 'ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack' when creating a grid?

Tags: python, printing, grid

I have been tring to make a more difficult grid with 16 words. I have made a grid with 9 words but am unable to do 16 words. I keep on getting the 'ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack' in my code?

```
#(Hard) This is the part of the program which puts the words in a Grid.
with open('WordsExt.txt') as f:
    wordshard = random.sample([x.rstrip() for x in f],16)
    gridhard = [wordshard[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(wordshard), 3)]
    for x,y,z  in gridhard:
        print (x,y,z)
```

Comment: Could put the entire error stack trace in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the error occurs because `gridhard` does contain less than 3 elements.

The last value of iterator `i` in the third line of your code example is 15, but `wordshard` is not longer than 16.  In that case, `gridhard` will only contain 1 letter, and hence, can not be unpacked into three values.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a 4x4 grid, so those `3`s need to become `4`s.

Also, you could use the `.join` method to build each row of your word grid, which makes the output format a little more flexible:

```
wordshard = [c*4 for c in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP']
gridhard = [wordshard[i:i + 4] for i in range(0, len(wordshard), 4)]
for row in gridhard:
    print(' '.join(row))
```

**output**

```
AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD
EEEE FFFF GGGG HHHH
IIII JJJJ KKKK LLLL
MMMM NNNN OOOO PPPP
```

If we change the last line to `print(' | '.join(row))` the output becomes:

```
AAAA | BBBB | CCCC | DDDD
EEEE | FFFF | GGGG | HHHH
IIII | JJJJ | KKKK | LLLL
MMMM | NNNN | OOOO | PPPP
```

Alternatively, we can get the same output by using the `*` "splat" unpacking operator, and specifying a separator string in the `print` call:

```
print(*row, sep=' | ')
```